# -bash: /usr/bin/vim: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, vim

I removed one line from .bashrc, basically a path to a software home directory and when I tried to source the bashrc it outputs the file content like several hundred times ending with

```
-bash: /usr/bin/modulecmd: Argument list too long
-bash: /apps/pyenv/bin/pyenv: Argument list too long
```

I cannot enter the file anymore, I get this error:

```
vi .bashrc 
-bash: /usr/bin/vim: Argument list too long
```

what did I do?

Answer (score -1):

Me answering my own question:
I don't know what happened, maybe someone can explain. Any command I entered was returning the 'Argument too long' message so I closed the terminal and started in a new one with no problem.

Comment: This isn't really going to be useful to anyone else. We don't know what you *actually* did to cause the problem, nor do we know why the problem was limited to one instance of the shell.